# BigQuery job still in RUNNING state after DELETE successful

Tags: python, sql, google-bigquery

I used the following Python code to delete all the data from a table in BigQuery, when I checked the table a few seconds after running the code, I found that the table is now empty, hence the delete must have succeeded. However, the job state still shows that it is in the RUNNING state.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery
import time

client     = bigquery.Client()
job_config = bigquery.QueryJobConfig()

job_config.priority = bigquery.QueryPriority.INTERACTIVE

sql = """DELETE FROM <table_name> WHERE TRUE"""

query_job = client.query( sql, job_config= job_config )
query_job = client.get_job( query_job.job_id )  # API request - fetches job

while query_job.state == "RUNNING":
    print( "Job {} is currently in state {}".format( query_job.job_id, query_job.state ) )
    time.sleep( 5 )

if query_job.errors != None:
    print( "Query Failed." )
    raise Exception( "Query Failed. Error: [ %s ]." % query_job.error_result )
```

What is going wrong here ? Why is the job not proceeding to the DONE state ? How can I check for successful execution via code ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you need to call `get_job` as part of the loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! That did the trick. Why don't you write it down as a full answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: Sure, added an answer (hopefully the syntax is correct). Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The trick is here:

```
query_job = client.get_job( query_job.job_id )  # API request - fetches job

while query_job.state == "RUNNING":
    print( "Job {} is currently in state {}".format( query_job.job_id, query_job.state ) )
    time.sleep( 5 )
```

`get_job` returns the status of the job at a point in time, but isn't updated automatically when the job status changes. Instead, you need to call `get_job` as part of the loop:

```
while True:
  query_job = client.get_job( query_job.job_id )  # API request - fetches job
  if query_job.state != "RUNNING":
    break
  print( "Job {} is currently in state {}".format( query_job.job_id, query_job.state ) )
  time.sleep( 5 )
```